# How to put different aks deployment within the same resource group/cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Current state:
I have all services within a cluster and under just one resource_group. My problem is that I have to push all the services every time and my deploy is getting slow.

What I want to do: I want to split every service within my directory so I can deploy it separately. Now I have a backend to each service, so that can have his own remote state and won't change things when I deploy. However, can I push still have all the services within the same resource_group? If yes, how can I achieve that? If I need to create a resource group for each service that I want to deploy separately, can I still use the same cluster?

*main.tf*

```yaml
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "2.23.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "${var.resource_group_name}-${var.environment}"
  location = var.location

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }
}
resource "tls_private_key" "key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "main" {

  name                            = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.environment}"
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  dns_prefix                      = "${var.dns_prefix}-${var.environment}"
  node_resource_group             = "${var.resource_group_name}-${var.environment}-worker"
  kubernetes_version = "1.18.6"

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = var.admin_username

    ssh_key {
      key_data = "${trimspace(tls_private_key.key.public_key_openssh)} ${var.admin_username}@azure.com"
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "default"
    node_count      = var.agent_count
    vm_size         = "Standard_B2s"
    os_disk_size_gb = 30
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = "false"
  }

  addon_profile {
    kube_dashboard {
      enabled = "true"
    }
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "Standard"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "40m"
    delete = "40m"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = var.client_id
    client_secret = var.client_secret
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  version          = "1.12.0"
  load_config_file = "false"

  host = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config[0].host

  client_certificate = base64decode(
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config[0].client_certificate,
  )

  client_key = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config[0].client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config[0].cluster_ca_certificate,
  )
}
```

backend.tf (for main)

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
}
```

client.tf (service that I want to deploy separately)

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "client" {
  metadata {
    name = "client"

    labels = {
      serviceName = "client"
    }
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }

  spec {

    progress_deadline_seconds = 600

    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        serviceName = "client"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          serviceName = "client"
        }
      }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "client" {
  metadata {
    name = "client"
  }

  spec {
    selector = {
      serviceName = kubernetes_deployment.client.metadata[0].labels.serviceName
    }

    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }
  }
}
```

backend.tf (for client)

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "test-storage"
    storage_account_name = "test"
    container_name = "terraform"
    key="test"
  }
}
```

deployment.sh

```
terraform -v
terraform init \
    -backend-config="resource_group_name=$TF_BACKEND_RES_GROUP" \
    -backend-config="storage_account_name=$TF_BACKEND_STORAGE_ACC" \
    -backend-config="container_name=$TF_BACKEND_CONTAINER" \

terraform plan
    
terraform apply -target="azurerm_resource_group.main" -auto-approve \
    -var "environment=$ENVIRONMENT" \
    -var "tag_version=$TAG_VERSION" \
```

PS: I can build the test resource-group from scratch if needed. Don't worry about his current state.

PS2: The state files are being saved into the right place, no issue about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy resources separately, you could take a look at `terraform apply` with this option.

```
  -target=resource       Resource to target. Operation will be limited to this
                         resource and its dependencies. This flag can be used
                         multiple times.
```

For example, just deploy a resource group and its dependencies like this,

```
terraform apply -target="azurerm_resource_group.main"
```

Comment: Even that my deploy doesn't fail, my client is not being updated. That's the result I receive: Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Comment: Do you just update the resource(edit the original terraform file) instead of deploying a new one? Could you remove the old state file then deploy these resources separately?

Comment: I completely removed the old resource-group. I just found that when I run terraform plan it shows the correct updates. I think the way I'm doing -target="azurerm_resource_group.main" is not correct.

Comment: Could you remove your old state files or rename them and deploy resources as my reply? Since terraform apply relies on your old states file. If the resource is displaying in the state file, then `terraform apply` does nothing. For a short test, You can just create a resource group with a vNET.

Comment: As you said, I've removed both my state files and also rebuild the cluster before running the new code. I still have the same issue, the client changes are not applying to my main resource_group/cluster.

Comment: I tried your code, it worked as expected when I did `terraform init`, `terraform plan`, `terraform apply` with target each resource one by one and do it step by step instead of using deployment.sh script. The other difference is that I use local states rather than storing it on a storage account but I don't think it will affect this case.See [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NZzh.png). I am using terraform version Terraform v0.13.0

Comment: `I've removed both my state files and also rebuild the cluster before running the new code. I still have the same issue, the client changes are not applying to my main resource_group/cluster.` Do you mean you have deployed all your configuration files, just update or change something in the `resource "kubernetes_service" "client"`, then you expect some update on the Azure portal? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I've deployed all my configuration files. I can see the state files and resource-group created as expected in my Azure portal. However, when I run terraform apply within my client build folder it doesn't change anything in my main resource group. Is that anything more you wanna know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220787/discussion-between-arthur-costa-and-nancy-xiong).